# ebay api GetOrders not returning Customer Address Info

Tags: php, magento, ebay-api

I am working on ebay2magento sync extension, and got stuck in getting ebay order details:

I am using GetOrders ebay Api.

Below is the xml request that I am using to get order data from ebay:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">
    <CreateTimeFrom>2007-12-01T20:34:44.000Z</CreateTimeFrom>
    <CreateTimeTo>2014-01-22T20:34:44.000Z</CreateTimeTo>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>authToken</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</GetOrdersRequest>​
```

Note: "authToken" is sellers auth token value.

I am trying to get Customer Shipping Address from order, but in  tag, I am getting only buyer's email.

Can any one help me, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show the spinnet of the response? It is interesting, this request should not work, because you've specified too large date range between CreateTimeFrom and CreateTimeTo. From [ebay specification](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/reference/ebay/GetOrders.html#Request.CreateTimeFrom) : > The maximum date range that may be specified with the CreateTimeFrom and CreateTimeTo fields is 90 days.

Comment: if the order / checkout is incomplete, you have no access to the shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
<OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
<Pagination>
<EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
<NumberOfDays>7</NumberOfDays>
<ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
<Version>823</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```